# I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with my code. Is this setup correctly?

Tags: java, file, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using a .txt file that has data in it formatted the same way throughout.

For example:

- title|format|onLoan|loanedTo|loanedOn
- title|format|onLoan|loanedTo|loanedOn
- title|format|onLoan|loanedTo|loanedOn
- title|format|onLoan|loanedTo|loanedOn

I am opening the file and then trying to transfer that information into class object and then put that object in a arrayList of that class.

The problem I am having is with the age old ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  I am not sure what is causing it.  It is probably something simple.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Library.open(Library.java:230)


Scanner input = null;
String mediaItemString = "";
MediaItem open = new MediaItem();  //class created for this object
String[] libraryItem;  
//try catch block for exception handling
try {
    input = new Scanner(new File("library.txt"));           
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        mediaItemString = input.nextLine();
        libraryItem = mediaItemString.split("\\|");
        System.out.println(libraryItem[0].toString());
        System.out.println(libraryItem[1].toString());  //error here, line 230               
        System.out.println(Boolean.parseBoolean(libraryItem[2].toString()));
        System.out.println(libraryItem[3].toString());
        System.out.println(libraryItem[4].toString());
        open.setTitle(libraryItem[0].toString());
        open.setFormat(libraryItem[1].toString());               
        open.setOnLoan(Boolean.parseBoolean(libraryItem[2].toString()));
        open.setLoanedTo(libraryItem[3].toString());
        open.setDateLoaned(libraryItem[4].toString());
        items.add(open);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("There was an error with the file.");
} finally {
    input.close();
}
```

Well I was hoping to split the string with delimiters and then assign those values to the MediaItem appropriately.

Comment: Is there an empty line in the file? Have you tried debugging to see the value of `mediaItemString` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: You need to learn to apply basic debugging techniques. Even withut using a debugger (which way easier than you think), just print the string and the array before accessing its elements, and you'll know what the problem is.

Comment: Interesting.  There is an extra line.  I went into the file and deleted the line and it works.  Upon further investigation...when I was writing to the file I was including a newline.

Comment: I completely overlooked checking mediaItemString.  The other println outputs were for debugging.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you found out. Hope you liked the feeling of discovering the problem by yourself :-)

Comment: I enjoy it most!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any missing value for a column. Also check for empty new lines.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some lines does not follow described format.

My suggection - add condition before array processing like

```
    ...
    libraryItem = mediaItemString.split("\\|");
    if(libraryItem.length <5) {
        log.error("Error: libraryItem.length is {} for string {}", libraryItem.length, mediaItemString);
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(libraryItem[0].toString());
    ...
```